# flashvars object was not working in mozilla browser

Tags: java, apache-flex

I am retrieving an flashvars object from JSP file. Like `userid = mx.core.Application.application.parameters.userJspid;`like this it is retrieving in IE browser. But not in FF (Mozilla), why it’s not retrieving is there any code i need to add it for Mozilla specially. Please help me in this, Thanks in advance.
i am loading in jsp like `<body scroll="no" onload="openWin();">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="main" width="100%" height="100%" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">

<param name="movie" value="main.swf"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"/>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>
<param name="FlashVars" value="userNid=<%=session.getAttribute("userNid")%>"/>
<embed src="main.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"width="100%" height="100%" name="main" align="middle" play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
</body>`like this

Comment: Post the code you're using to call the swf.

Answer (score 2):

With the embe method you are using above, the flashVars are not represented in the  portion of the whole embed code. When Firefox is reading this it is only processing attributes associated with , which is why you duplicate things like quality, bgcolor, etc. Try also duplicating the flashVars within  and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try replacing:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="userNid=<%=session.getAttribute("userNid")%>"/>
```

with

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="userNid=<%=session.getAttribute('userNid')%>"/>
```